# SQL Server : How to validate for yyyymmddhhmmss

Tags: sql-server, datetime, datetime-format

To avoid any conversion error, we'd like to validate if the target string can be converted to datetime using isdate formula, as follows.

```
CASE WHEN isdate(@targetstring)= 1 then cast(@targetstring as datetime) else '1900-01-01 00:00:00' end
```

It's working as expected, it returns 1 when it can be convertible.

```
select isdate('2021-06-22 23:27:00')
select isdate('20210622')
select isdate('20210622 23:00:00')
```

But yyyymmddhhmmss can't work as expected, it returns 0, even though the string can be converted to datetime.

```
select isdate('20210622230000')
```

If we use this, it seems to work.

```
select isdate(left('20210622230000', 8) + ' ' + substring('20210622230000', 9,2) + ':' + substring('20210622230000', 11,2) + ':' + substring('20210622230000', 13,2))
```

If there are any better idea, kindly let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Try `TRY_CONVERT`/`TRY_CAST` rather than the sometimes (often) wrong `ISDATE`/`ISNUMERIC`.

Comment: Though, for me, `'20210622230000'` can't be converted to a `datetime` without string manipulation; which makes the string *not* a valid date string on its own. Just because it can be, with manipulation, doesnt' mean that `ISDATE` or `TRY_CONVERT` are "clever" enough to know that.

Comment: In truth, it seems like the *real* problem is you are storing literal strings for date (and time) values.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks a lot for your prompt reply. Yeah, you're right. try_convert for '20210622230000' returns null. '20210622 23:00:00' is working correctly. We need to change yyyymmddhhmmss bit. Anyway, thanks a lot for your useful information:)

Comment: Not trying to be negative, but if it's not obvious this is bad database design. You only have this problem because the correct datatype wasn't enforced (datetime). You can't search on those dates in any meaningful way (date range, etc.) and it can't be indexed. Nor can you use the variety of SQL datetime functions on it (day, year, month, eomonth, etc). SQL Server will throw errors for any other use of those dates you can think of, not just this query. It's best to fix the reason that non-normalized (not even 1NF) data is being put into the database versus just using it as-is for queries.

Comment: @Zorkolot  Thanks for your frank opinion. We need to verify and convert to datetime, the string yyyymmddhhmiss provided by the other system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just saying you could trim down string manipulation using `STUFF()`

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(50)='20210622232715'

Select try_convert(datetime,stuff(stuff(stuff(@S,13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' '))
```

**Results**

```
2021-06-22 23:27:15.000
```

Comment: Many thanks, that's Perfect !! I never know about 'stuff'.  I confirmed that's working as expected like this --  SELECT   
    CASE WHEN try_convert(datetime,stuff(stuff(stuff('20210622230000',13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' ')) IS NULL   
    THEN '1900-01-01 00:00:00'  
    ELSE CONVERT(datetime,stuff(stuff(stuff('20210622230000',13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,' '))
END AS Result